# Rails: no route matches form for url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm trying to make a form where users can upload a file using the paperclip gem. Here is what I got so far:

in new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @replay, url: replay_path(@replay), :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :r_file %>

    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and here is my replay controller:

```
class ReplayController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @replay = Replay.new
    end

    def create
        @replay = Replay.create(params[:replay])
        if @replay.save
            redirect_to @replay
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @replay = Replay.find(params[:id])
        #puts @replay.attachment.file_name
    end

    def update
    end

    private

    def replay_params
        params.require(:replay).permit(:r_file, :map)
    end
end
```

and my routes:

```
  home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)      home#index
replay_index GET    /replay(.:format)          replay#index
             POST   /replay(.:format)          replay#create
  new_replay GET    /replay/new(.:format)      replay#new
 edit_replay GET    /replay/:id/edit(.:format) replay#edit
      replay GET    /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#show
             PATCH  /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#update
             PUT    /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#update
             DELETE /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#destroy
        root GET    /                          home#index
```

but I'm getting the following error in the form in new.html.erb:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"replay", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm not sure why :id is nil? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `url: replays_path` instead `url: replay_path(@replay)` currently form_for is referring to `show` action but you need to send file to `create` action of controller.

```
<%= form_for @replay, url: replays_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
```

**EDIT:**

As i can see your routes. your `index` action is referred by `replay_index` generally its `replays` if you have created your routes using Scaffolding . So in this case you need to add `url: replay_index_path`.

```
<%= form_for @replay, url: replay_index_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
```

> **Note:**  if you correct your routes, there is no need to mention
>   `url` option in form_for tag. it will automatically refer to create action when you submit form. it is recommended to correct your route.

Update your **routes.rb**. Create routes using `resource`

```
resources :replays
```

it creates seven different routes in your application, all mapping to the ReplayController. Each action maps to a specific CRUD operation in a database.

your routes should look like

```
    replays GET    /replay(.:format)          replay#index
            POST   /replay(.:format)          replay#create
 new_replay GET    /replay/new(.:format)      replay#new
edit_replay GET    /replay/:id/edit(.:format) replay#edit
     replay GET    /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#show
            PATCH  /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#update
            PUT    /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#update
            DELETE /replay/:id(.:format)      replay#destroy
```

Comment: After I do that, I get a new error:

undefined method `replays_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faee7842ef0>:0x007faee7891ca8>
Did you mean?  replay_path

Comment: where it is giving error now in HTML or controller?

Comment: in the HTML still, on the exact same line (form_for). It says undefined replays_path but there isn't a replays_path there.

Comment: i have edited my answer check it, add `url: replays_path`  for send  file to create action. Let me know if this is working now

Comment: Gave that a go, produced the same error (undefined method replays_path).

Comment: i didn't seen your routes earlier, check my edit section, now this will definitely going to work.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know it worked. you can accept my answer so that it will be helpful to others if they face same issue.

Comment: one more thing if you correct your routes, there is no need to mention `url ` option in form.it will automatically refer to create action . i recommend  you to correct your route.